# Export mysql database in ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I have been working on the grails project in ubuntu. And i am using mysql as database.
Can any one me in exporting the database.
Commands like these are not working for me in ubuntu.

```
mysqldump db_name > backup-db_name.sql
mysqldump -u userNameHere db_name > backup-db_name.sql
mysqldump -u userNameHere -p db_name > backup-db_name.sql
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say they're not working... What's happening?

Comment: At least the third one should work.